# Do I need to re-compile C++ files for redhat upgrade

Tags: c++, linux, redhat

We have one application written in C++ and already compiled and running on Redhat6. But recently we need to upgrade the Redhat from 6 to 8. Do I need to re-compile the application on Redhat8 or I can just easily copy those .so files to the new environment? Thanks

Comment: Try it and find out. We cannot possibly hope to know what library dependencies you have, and be able to intuitively cross-reference that with what RedHat changed. In general for any major version release you should recompile against the libraries for that version, so have a build for RH6, RH8, etc. As 6 and 8 were released 9 years apart, I'd be stunned if your RH6 build worked just fine on RH8.

Comment: Large OS updates might need rebuilds, because many of the base-libraries have changed. Or maybe even the ABI itself might have changed. Unfortunately there's really no single "yes" or "no" answer to this.

Comment: No definite answer possible.   It really depends on what libraries your application is using (you haven't specified) and how they have been affected by the redhat upgrade (ABI changes, dependencies on other libraries, etc).   It also depends on how you verify correct functioning of your program (say, do test cases built under RH6 still pass when copied across and run again under RH8?).

Comment: Failure to recompile is called *technical debt*. You'll run out of credit eventually.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on whether or not the application was linked against system libraries, or if it included its own dependency libraries separately. I'd recommend trying to use the existing binaries as is and if it works, great! You can migrate to Redhat 8 a little bit sooner.

Even if it does work, there's still benefits to re-compiling your application against newer versions of your dependencies, as that will ensure your application is protected by the latest security and performance updates to those libraries.